# Comparing strings word by word and row by row

Tags: r, string, string-comparison

I have two datasets that have two address columns. I want to merge the two datasets by the common address. But some of the addresses are intersections and the order of the street names is different in each dataset. Is there a way of asking Rstudio to compare the strings word by word and if there are more than two words matching, let me know? An example is:

"CABOT ST AT RUGGLES ST" and "RUGGLES ST AT CABOT ST"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code reorders the words in the addresses in alphabetical order, so then you can test if two addresses are the same

```
library(stringr)
df =  data.frame(address = c("CABOT ST AT RUGGLES ST", "RUGGLES ST AT CABOT ST"))

# split the address into words
list_split <- str_split(df$address,' ')
#[[1]]
#[1] "CABOT"   "ST"      "AT"      "RUGGLES" "ST"     

#[[2]]
#[1] "RUGGLES" "ST"      "AT"      "CABOT"   "ST"

# sort the words
list_sort <- map(list_split, sort)
#[[1]]
#[1] "AT"      "CABOT"   "RUGGLES" "ST"      "ST"     

#[[2]]
#[1] "AT"      "CABOT"   "RUGGLES" "ST"      "ST"  

# paste all the words reordered together
list_pasted <-  map(list_sort,function(x) paste(x,collapse= " "))
#[[1]]
#[1] "AT CABOT RUGGLES ST ST"

#[[2]]
# [1] "AT CABOT RUGGLES ST ST"

# unlist to convert to vector and assign to a new column
df$address_sorted <- unlist(list_pasted)
#                 address         address_sorted
#1 CABOT ST AT RUGGLES ST AT CABOT RUGGLES ST ST
#2 RUGGLES ST AT CABOT ST AT CABOT RUGGLES ST ST
```

If you have two address columns you can do the same for the other column and compare them together

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that simply comparing both strings for more than two similar words will be enough to solve your problem. However, it could be done this way, using the `str_split` function from the `stringr` package. I also added a way to remove unwanted words from the comparisons, like "ST" and "AT":

```
# List of words to exclude from the comparisons
excluded <- c("ST", "AT")

# Addresses to compare
ad_1 <- "CABOT ST AT RUGGLES ST"
ad_2 <- "RUGGLES ST AT CABOT ST"

# Get unique list of words in each address
ad_1_d <- unique(str_split(ad_1, " ")[[1]])
ad_2_d <- unique(str_split(ad_2, " ")[[1]])

# Remove words from the vector above
ad_1_d <- ad_1_d[!ad_1_d %in% excluded]
ad_2_d <- ad_2_d[!ad_2_d %in% excluded]

if (sum(ad_1_d %in% ad_2_d) >= 2 || sum(ad_2_d %in% ad_1_d) >= 2) {
  message("Similar addresses.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! what do you mean that this is not gonna be enough?

Comment: @Sani: For example, the words "ST" and "AT" appear in both addresses. Thus, the two addresses "THING1 ST AT THING2 ST" and "THING3 ST AT THING4 ST" would match when they shouldn't, if I understand your problem correctly. I fixed it by using "strictly more than 2" instead of "2 or more", but you should probably use a list of words, like "ST" and "AT" to exclude from your comparisons.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. What I need to do is to drop suffix words. After that, I'll just have "CABOT" and "RUGGLES". Thanks for your awesome help!